# R glmtree() memory error

Tags: r, memory-management, glm

I'm trying to use R's `glmtree` function. The size of my dataset is ~800K samples and ~300 features, which fits into my PC's memory. Trying to run the fit on the whole dataset throws an error, so I tried fitting to smaller subsets, and I encountered a strange behavior:

When I use randomly selected 1999 samples, the fit works and creates a ~1Mb glmtree object. However, when I use 2000 samples, I get the following error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 512.0 Gb

I don't understand the jump from a 1Mb object to half a tera. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you, it would be really great to have some more information about your dataset and the code that you use. Since this error message occurs most often when there are categorical variables with large level size implemented into the dataset.